# libclang get primitive value

Tags: c++, libclang

How can I get the value of a primitive literal using libclang?

For example, if I have a CXCursor of cursor kind CXCursor_IntegerLiteral, how can I extract the literal value.

---

UPDATE:

I've run into so many problems using libclang. I highly recommend avoiding it entirely and instead use the C++ interface clang provides. The C++ interface is highly useable and very well documented: http://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/annotated.html

The only purpose I see of libclang now is to generate the ASTUnit object for you as with the following code (it's not exactly easy otherwise):

```
ASTUnit * astUnit;
{
    index = clang_createIndex(0, 0);
    tu = clang_parseTranslationUnit(
        index, 0,
        clangArgs, nClangArgs,
        0, 0, CXTranslationUnit_None
        );
    astUnit = static_cast<ASTUnit *>(tu->TUData);
}
```

Now you might say that libclang is stable and the C++ interface isn't. That hardly matters, as the time you spend figuring out the AST with libclang and creating kludges with it wastes so much of your time anyway. I'd just as soon spend a few hours fixing up code that does not compile after a version upgrade (if even needed).

Answer (score 10):

Instead of reparsing the original, you already have all the information you need inside the translation unit :

```
if (kind == CXCursor_IntegerLiteral)
{
    CXSourceRange range = clang_getCursorExtent(cursor);
    CXToken *tokens = 0;
    unsigned int nTokens = 0;
    clang_tokenize(tu, range, &tokens, &nTokens);
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < nTokens; i++)
    {
        CXString spelling = clang_getTokenSpelling(tu, tokens[i]);
        printf("token = %s\n", clang_getCString(spelling));
        clang_disposeString(spelling);
    }
    clang_disposeTokens(tu, tokens, nTokens);
}
```

You will see that the first token is the integer itself, the next one is not relevant (eg. it's `;` for `int i = 42;`.

Comment: Oh cool! That said, do you know how to get either your or my solution to work with macros in the original source code? That is, if I have `#define N 1` `int x = N`, it would be good to get `1` from this instead of `N` or the empty string. What about with complicated macros as well?

Comment: Why does it return an extra ; after 1. I have observed that clang_getCursorExtent() also returns an extra column after integer literal. Why does it do that given the cursor is of type INTEGERLITERAL

Comment: FWIW this did not work for me with libclang-8. In test case where the IntegerLiteral is used as a size for a fixed length array the cursor extent appears to start way before just the stuff between the brackets `[]`. Note that the length is a macro expansion and TU is compiled with `CXTranslationUnit_DetailedPreprocessingRecord` so it may be related to that. @ThomasEding 's answer below did work for me.

Answer (score 6):

If you have access to a `CXCursor`, you can make use of the `clang_Cursor_Evaluate` function, for example:

```cpp
CXChildVisitResult var_decl_visitor(
    CXCursor cursor, CXCursor parent, CXClientData data) {
  auto kind = clang_getCursorKind(cursor);

  switch (kind) {
  case CXCursor_IntegerLiteral: {
    auto res = clang_Cursor_Evaluate(cursor);
    auto value = clang_EvalResult_getAsInt(res);
    clang_EvalResult_dispose(res);

    std::cout << "IntegerLiteral " << value << std::endl;

    break;
  }
  default:
    break;
  }

  return CXChildVisit_Recurse;
}
```

Outputs:

```
IntegerLiteral 42
```

Comment: how about get binary operator?

Answer (score 1):

I found a way to do this by referring to the original files:

```
std::string getCursorText (CXCursor cur) {
    CXSourceRange range = clang_getCursorExtent(cur);
    CXSourceLocation begin = clang_getRangeStart(range);
    CXSourceLocation end = clang_getRangeEnd(range);
    CXFile cxFile;
    unsigned int beginOff;
    unsigned int endOff;
    clang_getExpansionLocation(begin, &cxFile, 0, 0, &beginOff);
    clang_getExpansionLocation(end, 0, 0, 0, &endOff);
    ClangString filename = clang_getFileName(cxFile);
    unsigned int textSize = endOff - beginOff;

    FILE * file = fopen(filename.c_str(), "r");
    if (file == 0) {
        exit(ExitCode::CANT_OPEN_FILE);
    }
    fseek(file, beginOff, SEEK_SET);
    char buff[4096];
    char * pBuff = buff;
    if (textSize + 1 > sizeof(buff)) {
        pBuff = new char[textSize + 1];
    }
    pBuff[textSize] = '\0';
    fread(pBuff, 1, textSize, file);
    std::string res(pBuff);
    if (pBuff != buff) {
        delete [] pBuff;
    }
    fclose(file);
    return res;
}
```

Comment: This worked for me to get the expression for the length of a fixed length array in a field declaration with libclang-8.

Answer (score 1):

You can actually use a combination of libclang and the C++ interface.

The libclang `CXCursor` type contains a `data` field which contains references to the underlying AST nodes. 
I was able to successfully access the `IntegerLiteral` value by casting `data[1]` to the `IntegerLiteral` type.

I'm implementing this in [Nim](https://nim-lang.org) so I will provide Nim code, but you can likely do the same in C++.

```
let literal = cast[clang.IntegerLiteral](cursor.data[1])
echo literal.getValue().getLimitedValue()
```

The `IntegerLiteral` type is wrapped like so:

```
type
  APIntObj* {.importcpp: "llvm::APInt", header: "llvm/ADT/APInt.h".} = object
    # https://github.com/llvm-mirror/llvm/blob/master/include/llvm/ADT/APInt.h
  APInt* = ptr APIntObj

  IntegerLiteralObj* {.importcpp: "clang::IntegerLiteral", header: "clang/AST/Expr.h".} = object
  IntegerLiteral* = ptr IntegerLiteralObj


proc getValue*(i: IntegerLiteral): APIntObj {.importcpp: "#.getValue()".}
  # This is implemented by the superclass: https://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/classclang_1_1APIntStorage.html
proc getLimitedValue*(a: APInt | APIntObj): culonglong {.importcpp: "#.getLimitedValue()".}
```

Hope this helps someone :)